# Get document IDs from SOLR heatmap (geospatial) faceting

Tags: solr

I have a SOLR index with more than 100000 documents. I am doing a SOLR query with heatmap (geospatial) faceting to group them:

```
facet=true&facet.heatmap=lat_lon_rpt&facet.heatmap.distErrPct=0.01&facet.heatmap.format=ints2D&facet.heatmap.geom=[13.425293 48.792390 TO 24.741211 55.541065]
```

I get count (number of documents) in each grid cell but some cells only contain one document. Is it possible to get the document ID in such case? I do not want to read all 100000 documents and process them in PHP because it would be too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Solr facet heatmap response directly, no you cannot do this. The facet heatmap response operates similarly to how other Solr faceted responses operate, you get a value (in this case a spatial area) and a count. You could do an additional Solr query against the value (spatial area) to just return the IDS in that area.